# Get custom UITableViewCell using `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have UITableView which use custom UITableViewCell created from `.xib` file.
And I need to get to some properties of this cells but I always got the same cell.
For example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    WLS_AnswerCell *answerCell = (WLS_AnswerCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AnswerCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [answerCell setChecked:NO];

    return answerCell;
}
```

Getting cell's properties:

```
for (NSInteger j = 0; j < [contentTableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; j++) {
    WLS_AnswerCell *cell = (WLS_AnswerCell *)[(UITableView *)currentView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    if (cell.checked) {
       NSLog(@"Cell checked, cell  %@", cell);
       [answers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:j+1]];
    }
}
```

`NSlog` shows always `<WLS_AnswerCell: 0x8de1ee0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 40); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x8de2070>`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You are going about this the wrong way. The cell should only be a view. It should not contain data. Your table view's data source should be keeping track of which rows are selected. The cell should only display the selection indication.

Comment: Guys, sorry for stupid question. Error is in my loop :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in your for loop. The index path you create uses `i` for the row, and it should be `j` instead :)